# Vee-validate if/else input field

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I want to add a class (border 1px solid #ff0000) to an input element if there is an error. Like:

Error:

```
errors.has(name)
```

Input:

```
<input v-validate="validate" v-on:input="updateValue($event)" :type="type" :placeholder="placeholder"
               :name="name" :value="value" :class="classname" :id="id">
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your class with an `errors.has` condition

```html
<input v-validate="validate" :name="name" :class="{'classname': errors.has(name)}">
```